# MYSQL Updating tables with INNER JOIN and if

Tags: mysql

I made an SQL sentence that uses INNER JOIN, but I also want to add case that additional updates `gh.userGenbaStatus` when `gh.userGenbaStatus == 2`

```
UPDATE manager.user u INNER JOIN manager.genbahistory gh
    ON u.userId = gh.userId AND gh.genbaHistoryStatus = 1
    SET u.userStatus = 5, gh.genbaHistoryStatus = 0
    WHERE u.userId = #{userId}

    if(gh.userGenbaStatus==2){
    SET gh.userGenbaStatus = 1
    }
```

I wnat to insert that `if(){}` code fit with my update sql sentence. may I have any advice or help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your `if` pseudo code to use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE manager.user u
INNER JOIN manager.genbahistory gh
    ON u.userId = gh.userId
SET
    u.userStatus = 5,
    gh.genbaHistoryStatus = 0,
    gh.userGenbaStatus = CASE WHEN gh.userGenbaStatus = 2
                              THEN 1 ELSE gh.userGenbaStatus END
WHERE
    gh.genbaHistoryStatus = 1 AND
    u.userId = #{userId};
```

Comment: Reload the page...I'm on a cell phone and I have edited a couple of times.